# Как создать шаблон для страницы всех категории Woocoomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть такой url product-category/deserty/
Страница с выводом продукции всех категории

Если я открываю просто /product-category выдает 404. Скорее потому что нету шаблона
Как создать шаблон для страницы product-category/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По адресу /product-category/ будет искаться страница со слагом product-category

Иерархия шаблонов для этой страницы

```
page-product-category.php
page-{ID}.php
page.php
singular.php
index.php
```